# Find the stronger version of $9 ( a+b+c ) ^{2} ( ab+ac+bc ) ^{2}+108a^2b^2c^2-31abc ( a+b+c ) ^{3} \geqslant 0$

Tags: inequality, symmetric-polynomials, uvw

For $a,b,c \geqslant 0.$ Then $$9 ( a+b+c ) ^{2} ( ab+ac+bc ) ^{2}+108a^2b^2c^2-31abc ( a+b+c ) ^{3} \geqslant 0.$$
I use computer and found that the following stronger inequality holds for all reals of $a,b,c.$

$$\sum (a^2 -bc) \Big[9\, \left( a+b+c \right) ^{2} \left( ab+ac+bc \right) ^{2}+108\,{a}^{2 }{b}^{2}{c}^{2}-31\,abc \left( a+b+c \right) ^{3}\Big] \geqslant \frac{81}{4} \sum ab \prod \left( a-b \right) ^{2}$$

And also:
$$\sum (a^2 -bc) \Big[9\, \left( a+b+c \right) ^{2} \left( ab+ac+bc \right) ^{2}+108\,{a}^{2 }{b}^{2}{c}^{2}-31\,abc \left( a+b+c \right) ^{3}\Big] \geqslant {\frac {27}{4}}\, \left( a+b+c \right) ^{2} \prod \left( a-b \right) ^{2}$$

Any another inequality$?$

Comment: I gave a method to find a stronger inequality of an inequality in your another post. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3688900/find-the-stronger-inequality-of-frac1ab2c22c-frac1bc2a22a?rq=1

Comment: @RiverLi Thanks, you try use it with this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is the following stronger version.

> Let $a$, $b$ and $c$ be non-negatives. Prove that:
> $$9 ( a+b+c ) ^{2} ( ab+ac+bc ) ^{2}+108a^2b^2c^2-31abc ( a+b+c ) ^{3}\geq$$
> $$\geq4(3\sqrt3-4)(a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc)abc.$$

The equality occurs for $a=b=c$ and for $(a,b,c)=t(6+4\sqrt3,1,1)$, where $t\geq0$ and for any cyclic permutations of the last.

Even if we'll replace $4(3\sqrt3-4)$ on $4$, the BW does not help here!

By the way, this inequality we can prove by $uvw$ immediately:

it's equivalent to $f(v^2)\geq0,$ where $f$ increases.

Indeed, let $a+b+c=3u$, $ab+ac+bc=3v^2$ and $abc=w^3$.

Thus, we need to prove that:
$$729u^2v^4+108w^6-31\cdot27u^3w^3\geq4(3\sqrt3-4)(27u^3-27uv^2)w^3$$ or $f(v^2)\geq0,$ where
$$f(v^2)=27u^2v^4+4w^6-31u^3w^3-4(3\sqrt3-4)(u^3-uv^2)w^3.$$
But $$f'(v^2)=54u^2v^2+4(3\sqrt3-4)uw^3\geq0,$$
which says that $f$ increases and it's enough to prove our inequality for the minimal value of $v^2$, which by $uvw$ happens for equality case of two variables.

Since our inequality is homogeneous and for $w^3=0$ it's obvious, it's e enough to assume $b=c=1$, which gives:
$$9(a+2)^2(2a+1)^2+108a^2-31(a+2)^3a\geq4(3\sqrt3-4)(a^3-3a+2)a$$ or $$(a-1)^2(a-6-4\sqrt3)^2\geq0$$ and we are done.

It seems that this inequality is true for any reals $a$, $b$ and $c$,

but it's another problem (the previous reasoning does not help because $v^2$ can be negative).

Comment: How would you prove it ? Can you explain please ?

Comment: Yes, can be also kills by pqr method.

Comment: @user9026 I am very busy now. I'll post my proof in evening. Open another topic with your attempts and maybe someone other will help you.

Comment: (+1) It is a nice solution.

Comment: I upvote and accept for you, nice inequallity also.

Comment: $k=4(3\sqrt{3}-4)$ is the best constant here$,$ by the way your inequality is also true for all a,b,c are reals. Congrats!

Comment: In proof of $uvw$ for $w^3$. When we got $Max{0,f(x_2)}\le w^3\le f(x_1)$ it works when $g(x)=x^3-3ux^2+3v^2x$ is continuous function in $[a;b]$. Can you show me interval which $g(x)$ is continuous?

Comment: @Word Shallow $g$ is continues because $g$  is a polynomial.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg: Which interval for $g$ is continuous function?

Comment: @Word Shallow $(-\infty,+\infty)$ Maybe do you mean something different?